# Comparing UTC and Not-UTC formatted dates in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I'm trying to compare two dates in javascript which are formatted differently. Namely:

2015-09-30T00:00:00 and 9/30/2015 12:00:00 AM

The former is UTC and the latter is not in UTC format. Logically, I am referring to the same date/time here but I can't come up with a way to compare them that will return true. Creating a new Date object with each ends up with different results (due to UTC offset with my local time zone).

What am I missing?

Comment: Convert all dates to UTC before comparing them

Answer (score 0):

Ended up concluding that tagging on a "UTC" to the second date format before creating the Date object leads to an output consistent with the UTC formatted date.